# WordPress custom pagination isn't working well

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, pagination

I am working on a WordPress project, In this project according to the requirement, I implement the custom pagination for pagination. It works well when we click to page 2, 3 etc. but when i on the other page than first page and want to move on first page and click the 1 link then its not working. I don't understand what the problem is.

Code of my custom pagination:

```
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {
        if (empty($pagerange)) {
            $pagerange = 2;
        }
        global $paged;
        if (empty($paged)) {
            $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
        }
        if ($numpages == '') {
            global $wp_query;
            $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
            if(!$numpages) {
              $numpages = 1;
            }
        }
        $pagination_args = array(
            'base'            => '%_%',
            'format'          => '?paged=%#%',
            'total'           => $numpages,
            'current'         => $paged,
            'show_all'        => true,
            'end_size'        => 1,
            'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
            'prev_next'       => True,
            'prev_text'       => esc_html__('Prev','textdomain'),
            'next_text'       => esc_html__('Next','textdomain'),
            'type'            => 'list',
            'add_args'        => false,
            'add_fragment'    => ''
        );
        $paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);
        if ($paginate_links) {
            echo "<nav class='pagination-nav'>".$paginate_links."</nav>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution for this problem. There is need to change in the base of the code:

```
'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your function custom_pagination() apply front_page, maybe your theme have special template-part for the first page of your posts list page.

There is many way, begin searching in your theme directory the file part where is the main loop and look for:

if( (is_home() || is_front_page())  ){ ... }

Maybe you have a section with:

if (!is_paged()){ .... }

That include special part template for the first page.

EDIT: Sorry I had read bad your question and my poor english, can you please be more specific, what is the bad link showed on the inspector for the first page, and what is the expected link ?

Comment: I used this function on the custom templates. When i inspect the 1 link then its url is empty, but in the insepection of 2,3 etc links i got the proper url.

Comment: In the simple words pagination works well for all links instead of 1 page link. Means when i move to other page instead of 1 page and want to go back to 1 page then pagination is not working.